# How can i use common toolbar with a bar button item for all ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

How can I add a common toolbar with a UIBarButtonItem  for all `ViewControllers`

Comment: At which position you want to add toolbar?

Comment: bottom of the all screen...

Answer (score 0):

You should use navigation controller. select navigation controller from story board and from `attribute inspector` check `shows toolbar` and you will get toolbar in every viewcontroller.

[image]

You can see tool bar at bottom and you can add bar button items to it.

hope this will help :)

Comment: I have used this...it is showing toolbar in only one viewcontroller which is connected with navigation controller.Do i have to use same navigation controller for all uivewcontroller?

Comment: It's depends on requirement. You can use multiple navigation controller as well single.

Answer (score 0):

Create toobar in your navigation controller and then
add this

self.toolbarItems = self.navigationController.toolbarItems

in viewdidload  method of your every controller